# How to make migration use connection string from appsettings.developmente.json?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

i'm trying to make migration using appsetting.development.json but the migration only use the connection string from app.settings.json, how do i change this?

```
appsetting.development.json

{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    },
    "ConnectionStrings": {
      "ConexaoPadrao": "Server=localhost;Database=Agenda;Uid=root;Pwd=root;"
    }
  }
}
```

```
appsetting.json

{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "ConexaoPadrao": "Server=localhost;Database=Agenda;Uid=root;Pwd=root;"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

so appsetting.json is the default for your project as far as json settings are concerned when adding others like production or staging it is necessary that you have configured an overlay in your Startup, defaulting to your envariment example:

I have two appsettings.json: first appsettings.json this is the default one, and the appsettings.development.json the one that will somehow be merged with the appsettings.json when you have your envirement set to development

How to configure the environment ?

your project has a "Properties" folder with a lounchSettings.json file inside it you will find the "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" key or if you are using something other than the .netCore ASPNET_ENVIROMENT its value is what will dictate which appsettings will be merged with the default

Configuring the Program if it doesn't work natively:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
{
    var builder = new HostBuilder()
        .ConfigureHostConfiguration(configHost =>
        {
            configHost
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        })
```

make this configuration and everything will be fine...